# Clearcase installation

Tags: installation, clearcase

Can somebody let me know the best way to installation clear case application on a AIX server.

Clearcase version 7.1.2

If we have the method for uninstallation , it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should follow the general rules for ClearCase installation on Unix.
I have detailed one in "[How do you install ClearCase 7.1 on a Unix-based server with no GUI and no internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49786/how-do-you-install-clearcase-7-1-on-a-unix-based-server-with-no-gui-and-no-inter)".

There are only a few of [feature issues with AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_ms_platforms_guide.doc/clearcase_on_unix.htm#sii-unix-91020).

The silent uninstall procedure for ClearCase is covered in "[ClearCase 7.1 Silent Uninstall by example on UNIX or Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392235)".

> CD to the directory `/var/ibm/InstallationManager/uninstall` on the installed system.
>   Download the appropriate operating system response file from the following technote:
>   **[Sample uninstall response files for IBM Rational ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376355)**
>   Run the following command in the above directory:
>
> Example:

```
uninstall --launcher.ini silent-uninstall.ini -input /root/clearcase_uninstall_response_sol_x86.xml
```

> In the previous example the response file is

```
/root/clearcase_uninstall_response_sol_x86.xml
```

> This will uninstall ClearCase from the system.
>   The following will uninstall Install Manager from the above said directory:

```
uninstall --launcher.ini silent-uninstall.ini
```

Comment: Do you have the steps for un-installtion?

Comment: @user1383839 I have updated the answer with the un-installation steps.